# Why does $\lim_{x\to0^+}\mathrm{sgn}\left(x\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$ not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\mathrm{sgn}\left(x\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$

Why does this limit not exist (at least according to Wolframalpha)? I've encountered an exam question and there was a question like this, not $\mathrm{sgn(x)}$ but $f(x)$. $\mathrm{sgn(x)}$ is the possible $f$ I can think of.

I would say it is $1$ since inside of $\mathrm{sgn(x)}$ is $0^+$. I see that it oscillates infinitely many times as it gets closer to $0$ but how does this affect it? Does this make the inside not go to $0^+$, and if so how?

$$\mathrm{sgn(x)}=\begin{cases}1 & x>0\\ 0 & x = 0\\-1& x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: It depend on how you define the sign function at $0$. If $sgn(0)=1$, then the limit does exist, if $sgn(0)=0$ (or any other value but $1$), then $\sin(1/x^2)$ will be $0$ infinitely many time in any neighborhood of $0$, and thus, $sgn(x\sin(1/x^2))$ will switch infinitely many time between $0$ and $1$ in any neighborhood of $0$... Therefore, the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit doe not exist, because $f(x_n)=0$ if $\;x_n=\dfrac1{n\pi}$ and $f(x)=1$ if $\;x_n=\dfrac 1{\frac\pi 2+n\pi}\quad (n\in\mathbf N)$, and both sequences converge to $0$.